# Creating Like & view Count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im working on a project using Ruby on rails.
The website currently allows somebody to create a post & view however i want to add a way a visitir can like the post and also see how many views there have been. im super new to ruby on rails so apologies if this is basic stuff lol

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1):

use the gem called **[punching_bag](https://github.com/biola/punching_bag)** to achieve the view count functionality. 
**Usage**: follow the read me
You'll have to use like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post.punch(request)
  end
end
```

to get all hits:

```
@post.hits
```

use the gem called **[acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)** to achieve the like count functionality.
**Usage**: follow the read me

Comment: ive tried to install gem but i get permissoins denied error im using macbook/terminal

Comment: you added the gems in Gemfile I am sure. If not, try sudo gem install